# partition map check failed because no slices were found

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I own an early 2011 MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Mavericks. Recently, I tried to make 50 GB partition using Disk Utility but the whole process didn't complete, and I had to restart the system as it hanged (Even Force Quit wasn't working). Upon reboot, I saw that I was missing 50GB space. When I tried to verify the disk, it showed me the following error:

"Partition map check failed because no slices were found."

Can I fix it without using external drive? Please help.

Comment: Did the accepted solution solve your problem?

Comment: Plain old reboot then re-try worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reboot into Single User Mode (hold cmd-S on boot)
2. Run `/sbin/fsck -fy`

   <sup>`fsck` is File System Consistency checK. `-f` forces the process, and `-y` assumes yes.

   This will basically run Disk Utility's Repair Disk, but outside of the OS so that is has full read/write to the disk.</sup>
3. Once complete, `reboot`

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what the command does and why running it would help them?

Comment: @cksum Added explanation

Comment: @grgarside I am getting the same error message as OP, but on an external drive. (And options to repartition are greyed out.) How might I modify this command to help me?

Comment: How do you target an external drive with this command?

Comment: @Alex I've not tried this in single user mode, but once you've mounted the disk, you should be able to do it with `sudo /sbin/fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s1`

Answer (score 0):

Run the fstab command and remove all the setting there, then write the command. What I had there was preventing my Windows BootCamp partition from mounting. After removing it everything worked fine.
http://www.cnet.com/how-to/prevent-a-partition-from-mounting-in-os-x/

Comment: What do you mean by "write the command"

Answer (score 0):

I recieved "Partition map check failed because no slices were found.” from Disk Utility but perhaps for different reasons.

I had to re**MOUNT** (either it's a "right-click" or a button) the partition from Disk Utility and then **Repair** the partition.

Then it worked - heart attack / data loss averted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the following the method of the link below helped me.

https://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/#comment-127930

Comment: Please give a few details related to the link.